# Problem with using naudiodon / portaudio?

Tags: node.js, audio, dependencies, portaudio

When I try the "playing audio streaming audio data" from the naudiodon library I only get noise on the speaker. I'm interested in how to get real sound from an app (for example when playing music from youtube). I wonder if the sound is then saved in my case in stream4800.wav?
I wonder what all the dependency I need for the project?
When I just record over a microphone with `inOptions: {}` I get a successfully saved stream (sound). But when I want to get the sound out of the speakers `outOptions: {}` then the story becomes unclear to me.

Here is an example of my code:

```
const portAudio = require('naudiodon');
const wav = require("wav");

const ao = new portAudio.AudioIO({
outOptions: {
    channelCount: 2,
    sampleFormat: portAudio.SampleFormat64Bit,
    sampleRate: 44100,
}
});

const name = "stream4800.wav";
const file = fs.createReadStream(`./${name}`);
const reader = new wav.Reader(); 

ao.start();
reader.on("data",chunk=>ao.write(chunk));
file.pipe(reader);
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Hi please check the audio file [stream4800.wav] is Mono or Sterio. I would recommend you to use sterio file with applicable sampleRate will help you out.